# Can the New Relic Python agent track external service requests that don't use httplib?

Tags: python, newrelic

Using [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/) on a [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) application, some external services are being tracked and some are not. I've noticed that the ones that work utilize [httplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) while the others are using Tornado's [HTTP client](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html), which directly communicates with a socket.

My assumption is that the New Relic agent is hooked into the httplib, because under the hood httplib uses the same socket.

Is there anyway to track these requests as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The New Relic python agent does not currently support Tornado's HTTP client, but keep an eye on the release notes for any changes in the future:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/releases/python

You can also find a list of currently instrumented external service modules here:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/python/instrumented-python-packages#external-web-services